# Using expo vector icon in react native skia?

Tags: react-native, skia

How to use expo vector icon in react native skia.

I want to use this icon,

`<Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />` in skia Canvas or Box

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use vector icons directly but you can add the icon as an `SVG` image like this:

```
import {
  Canvas,
  ImageSVG,
  useSVG
} from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
 
const ImageSVGDemo = () => {
  // Alternatively, you can pass an SVG URL directly
  // for instance: const svg = useSVG("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg");
  const svg = useSVG(require("../../assets/checkmark.svg"));
  return (
    <Canvas style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      { svg && (
        <ImageSVG
          svg={svg}
          x={0}
          y={0}
          width={256}
          height={256}
        />)
      }
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

and the `checkmark.svg` file will be:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-1.25 16.518l-4.5-4.319 1.396-1.435 3.078 2.937 6.105-6.218 1.421 1.409-7.5 7.626z"/></svg>
```